# set footnotes below paired columns using reledpar and reledmac

Tags: footnotes, columns, reledmac, reledpar

I am using reledpar and reledmac to transcribe a two-column Latin text, with 4 levels of footnotes. Footnotes line up at the bottom left of page (as shown in the MWE). Is there a way to set them below the relevant column?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[top=2.8cm, bottom=2.8cm, left=1.9cm, right=1.9cm]{geometry} 

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
%to remove lines above footnotes

\usepackage[series={A,B,C},noend,noeledsec]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\alph{footnoteB}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteC}{\roman{footnoteC}}

\usepackage{perpage} 
\MakePerPage{footnote@typeset}
\MakePerPage{footnoteA@typeset}
\MakePerPage{footnoteB@typeset}
\MakePerPage{footnoteC@typeset}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{{\normalsize Notes}}

\usepackage{endnotes}

\linenummargin{left}
\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{.44\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{.44\textwidth}
\setlength{\columnrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\setlength{\beforecolumnseparator}{0.06\textwidth}
\setlength{\aftercolumnseparator}{0.06\textwidth}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=medieval]{latin}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\raggedbottom 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\setstretch{1.2}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\footnotesize
\usepackage{microtype} 

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=Maroon, urlcolor=gray, hyperfootnotes=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setstretch{1.2}

\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\firstlinenumR{1000000000}
% to not put line numbering on the right side
\parindent=0pt

Text text text\footnote{Comment about the manuscript.} text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
\vskip 10mm

\noindent\fbox{%
\parbox{\textwidth}{
{\small London: Library MS. xyz f. 1}
}}
\vskip 5mm

\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
{\footnotesize 
\textbf{OPENING TEXT} \\
text text text text\footnoteA{Spelling variant} text text\footnoteA{Spelling variant} text text text \\
text text text text text text text text text text text text\footnoteA{Another spelling variant} \\
\ldots \\ 
text text text text text text\footnoteA{Spelling variant} text text \\
text text text text text text text text text\footnoteB{Reference to biblical source.} 
}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
{\footnotesize 
text text text text text\footnoteC{Grammar} text text text text \\
text text text text text text text\footnoteA{Spelling variant} \\
text text text text text text text\footnoteA{Spelling variant} text text text text \\
\ldots \\ 
text text text text text text text text\footnoteB{Reference to literary source.} \\
text text text\footnoteC{Grammar} text text text text text  
}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs} 
\Columns

\clearpage

\noindent\fbox{%
\parbox{\textwidth}{
{\small London: Library MS. xyz f. 1v}
}}
\vskip 5mm

\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
{\footnotesize 
\textbf{OPENING TEXT} \\
text text text text\footnoteA{Spelling variant} text text text text text \\
text text text text text text text text text text text text\footnoteA{Another spelling variant} \\
\ldots \\ 
text text text text text text\footnoteC{Grammar} text text \\
text text text text text text text\footnoteC{Grammar} text text 
}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
{\footnotesize 
text text text text text text text text text\footnoteB{Reference to biblical source.} \\
text text text text text text text\footnoteA{Unusual spelling variant} \\
text text text text text text text\footnoteA{Spelling variant} text text text text \\
\ldots \\ 
text text text text text text text text\footnoteB{Reference to literary source.} \\
text text text\footnoteC{Grammar} text text text text text  
}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs} 
\Columns

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: no, there is not. Is is a asked feature, but for now I have no ideal how to implement it.

Comment: Oh, too bad. Thanks.